# PHP から MySQL のタイムアウト設定はできますか？

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

CakePHP で作られている特定の検索画面から `$this->[モデル]->find...` メソッドでクエリを実行した際、MySQL のタイムアウト時間を指定したいです。

`set_time_limit()` 関数ですとスクリプトのタイムアウトは有効ですが、DBの処理時間は対応していないようです。

そもそも可能なのか、分かる方がいらしたらご教授お願いします。

- CentOS  ：6.3
- PHP     ：5.3.3
- MySQL   ：5.1.58
- CakePHP ：2.3.9

Comment: http://hitotsu.ashita-sanuki.jp/e155057.html
リンクのini_set("mysql.connect_timeout", タイムアウト時間);
ではダメでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今のところできないと思います。[MySQL5.7.4以降でできるようになる](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_statement_time)ようです。PostgreSQLでは可能なのですが。

どうしてもやろうと思うなら、`show processlist` を叩いて実行時間の長いQueryをkillするスクリプトを実行しまくるとか、`information_schema.processlist` から同様のことをするかしかないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: できないですか、ご回答ありがとうございました！